# Selenium: Click on a "<div><a></a></div>" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to click on a button. It has this structure:

[image: HTML Code]

```
<div class="button-wrapper" id="button-verify-wrapper">
       <a x-ng-click="verifySfdcConnection()" class="clearfix float-left button-green">
            <div class="icon-green icon-green-verify"></div>
            <div class="button-label ng-binding">Verify Connection</div>
        </a>
         <div x-ng-class="{'connection-verified':wizardData.inputSource.sfdc.connectionStatus}" x-ng-show="wizardData.inputSource.sfdc.connectionStatus" style="" class="connection-verified"></div>
      </div>
```

Any help how to do it? I tried this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='button-verify-wrapper']/a/div[1]")).click();
```

But it doesn't help.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't help?? Is there any exception?? And are you sure desired `div` element is clickable or `a` element is clickable??

Comment: I Think is a link inside a Button.. just not exception, just don't click it. this is the button of the code: http://imgur.com/a/OmcDS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `<a>` element is clickable here. You should try to locate `<a>` element instead and perform `click()` action as below :-

- using `By.cssSelector()` :-

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#button-verify-wrapper > a")).click();
  ```
- using `By.linkText()` :-

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Verify Connection")).click();
  ```
- using `By.xpath()` :-

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[normalize-space(.) = 'Verify Connection']")).click();
  ```

If you're still unable to perform click, try as an alternate solution using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].cli‌​ck()", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#button-verify-wrapper > a")));
```

Comment: I tried both, doesn't work. The curious here is... it haven't exception... i guess.... is clicking the text but not the real button.

Comment: But in provided HTML it clearly looks that click event is receiving by `a` element because JavaScript function `verifySfdcConnection()`  is calling on `a` element on click event.

Comment: Try once using `JavascriptExecutor` to perform click as `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#button-verify-wrapper > a")));` and let me know..

Comment: It looks copy paste issue, try to type same manually and perform click and let me know..

Answer (score 0):

You should click on the link using a css selector like:
    `a[x-ng-click*='verifySfdcConnection']`

Comment: I tried this: 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[x-ng-click*='verifySfdcConnection']")).click();

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.id("button-verify-wrapper")).click();

Note: 1. if ID or class name is directly given no need to use xpath, can directly use By.id and By.class
2. To perform an action on web element we should know the properties of that element ex. if it is not a button you can not perform click on it

Comment: <a> is link tag you can perform click action on it

Answer (score 0):

try this: `$("#button-verify-wrapper > a").click()`

Comment: Tried this:
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#button-verify-wrapper > a")).click();   

Doesn't work.

Comment: Is the element in an IFrame ? if yes that will not work you need to switch to IFrame

Comment: i've already solve this issue with "JavascriptExecutor", thanks anyway :)